# Synonymize [off-topic] into [scope]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, meta

They are referring to the same thing, have no tag wiki, are synonymous, and really should be synonymized.

[off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic)

[scope](/questions/tagged/scope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. This has been done.